# Possibly not complete answer when integrating using substitution

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$$\int e^{\sqrt{x}} \,dx $$

1. Making substitution $ u= e^{\sqrt{x}} $
2. $ \ln(u) = \sqrt{x} $ (do no know how to call that (taking logarithm of both sides..?))
3. $ x = \ln^2(u) $
4. Derivating both sides $ dx = 2 \frac{\ln(u)}{u} du \ $

The logarithm then is equal to:

$$ 2e^{\sqrt{x}}(\ln({\sqrt x}) - 1) + C $$

My question is:

Do I need to downgrade the $\ln({\sqrt x})$ (because it got upgraded in the substitution), so that i will get $ \sqrt x $

In which cases such 'downgrades' are needed?

This is what I get with WolframAlpha [image]

Comment: As an aside, $\quad\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-\sqrt[n]x}dx~=~n!$

Comment: @Lucian how can this fact be practicaly used in solving this integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $u=e^\sqrt{x}$ is needlessly complicated.

Set $u=\sqrt{x}$ instead so the integral becomes

$$ \int 2e^u u\,\mathrm{d}u $$

and then [integrate by parts](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegrationbyParts.html).

Comment: you are right..

Comment: What do you mean by "Setting $u = e^{\sqrt x}$ is not a substitution"? It can be done using that substitution using pretty much the same steps as you did.

Comment: Yeah, i got curious about that one too

Comment: you will get 2* integral(ln(u))

Comment: @MocialovBoris so? integrate by parts and you get an answer.

Comment: @Kaster Yes, I am asking: why 'it wont get you anywhere'? you will have '2* integral(ln(u))' and can proceed further, only get wrong answer

Comment: @MocialovBoris sorry I confused you with the answerer :) I don't see why you get wrong answer. Prolly simple algebraic mistake. I got correct answer.

Comment: @Kaster arghh.. surely it is an algebraic mistake.. tried to solve few time making the same mistake every time..

Comment: @MocialovBoris please, see Mike's answer. I'm not sure I got your last comment right. Is it genuine regret that you couldn't get it right, or you sarcastically implying that $u = e^{\sqrt x}$ is not a way to go...

Comment: @Kaster sorry for the wrong choice of words, maybe, but I am just saying that I've done same mistake 3 time trying to get to the right answer. I clear my head and solved this problem first by substituting e^sqrt(x) and then by substituting sqrt(x)

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=u^2$  hence we have $dx=2udu$ and $\int e^\sqrt{x} \,dx=\int 2ue^{u} \,du$, know by integrate by parts
 we have $$\int 2ue^{u} \,du=2(u-1)e^{u}+c=2(\sqrt{x}-1)e^\sqrt{x}+c$$

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by downgrades.  Still, I can continue with your solution and let you see where you might have made a mistake.  Using your substitution, the integral becomes

$$\int2\ln udu$$

which you may remember is $2u(\ln u-1)$.  If not, it can be proven with integration by parts.  I think this is what you were going for.  However, substituting back, we get

$$2e^{\sqrt x}(\ln e^{\sqrt x}-1)=2e^{\sqrt x}(\sqrt x-1)$$

which matches Wolfram's answer.

Comment: Yes, i simply lost 'e' on my way to the correct answer.. 3 times in the row :)

Comment: The 'downgrade' makes no sense here.. That was my ignorance of solving integrals